# Mounting error: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'

Tags: partitioning, mount

lsblk output:

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1                      8:1    0 931.5G  0 part /mnt/storage_hdd
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
nvme0n1                   259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1               259:1    0   1.1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2               259:2    0     2G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3               259:3    0 950.8G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
```

I got the error: /mnt/storage_ssd: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.
when I try to mount the SSD partition nvme0n1p3 (remaining 850 GB). Ubuntu 20.04. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? What "that partition" you are trying to mount? I see all partitions mounted.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot some important details. Yeah, I use Ubuntu and I am trying to use the remaining 850GB in nvme0n1p3.

Comment: I am not sure you can mount a partition containing an lvm. You can expand the lvm though.